# python - list a dictionary using raw_input

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

I'm using the following line to make a question with options from a dictionary

```
int(raw_input("Please select one of the following options %s: " % str(dict_options).strip('{}')))
```

This is the output, for example:

```
Please select one of the following options: 1: 'Development', 2: 'Certification', 3: 'Production'
```

This is the output I need:

```
Please select one of the following options:
1) Development
2) Certification
3) Production
```

There anyway to change the raw_input line?
For some reason PyCharm need to put a text on the raw_input() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the commas with newline characters by doing `.replace(',', '\n')`. The code looks something like:

```
dict_options = {1: 'Development', 2: 'Certification', 3: 'Production'}
print " " + str(dict_options).strip('{}').replace(',', '\n')
```

OUTPUT

```
 1: 'Development'
 2: 'Certification'
 3: 'Production'
```

The first space' purpose is to align the options.

If you want to replace the colon with a `)` you can add an additional replace: `.replace(':', ')')`

If you want to get rid of the quotes you can do an additional: `.replace("'", '')`

etc.

**Example**

```
dict_options = {1: 'Development', 2: 'Certification', 3: 'Production'}

print " " + str(dict_options).strip('{}') \
                    .replace(',', '\n') \
                    .replace(':', ')') \
                    .replace("'", '')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 1) Development
 2) Certification
 3) Production
```